# Соединение объектов из разных потоков в QT. Не соединяет

Tags: многопоточность, потоки-данных, qt

1) Создаю объект со слотом run() в основном потоке (прямо в main()):

```
Function* func = new Function;
```

2) Запускаю асинхронно serverThreadGlobal:

```
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(serverThreadGlobal,func);
```

3) Внутри функции создаю объект класса с сигналом runIt и соединяю сигнал и слот:

```
int serverThreadGlobal(Function* func)
{
    std::cout<<"serverThreadGlobal\n";
    Server* server = new Server;
    QObject::connect(server,SIGNAL(runIt(int)),func,SLOT(run(int)));
//тут испускается сигнлал emit runIt(0);
    server->serverCycle(func);
    return 1;
}
```

4) Не соединяет! (слот void Function::run(int n) не срабатывает)

Код функции serverCycle

```
void Server::serverCycle(Function* func)
{
    emit runIt(0);
    while(1)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        emit runIt(0);
        std::cout<<"working\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соединение происходит. Но слот никогда не сработает. Объясню почему.
QObject::connect(server,SIGNAL(runIt(int)),func,SLOT(run(int))); этот метод, кроме этих четырёх параметров имеет и пятой параметр по умолчанию. Он задаёт тип соединения.

Qt supports these signal-slot connection types:

1)Auto Connection (default) If the signal is emitted in the thread which the receiving object has affinity then the behavior is the same as the Direct Connection. Otherwise, the behavior is the same as the Queued Connection."

2)Direct Connection The slot is invoked immediately, when the signal is emitted. The slot is executed in the emitter's thread, which is not necessarily the receiver's thread.

3)Queued Connection The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.
Blocking Queued Connection The slot is invoked as for the Queued Connection, except the current thread blocks until the slot returns.
Note: Using this type to connect objects in the same thread will cause deadlock.

4)Unique Connection The behavior is the same as the Auto Connection, but the connection is made only if it does not duplicate an existing connection. i.e., if the same signal is already connected to the same slot for the same pair of objects, then the connection is not made and connect() returns false.

По умолчанию сотит AutoConnection. Что это означает? Если у вас два соединённых объекта находятся в одном и том же потоке, то слот будет вызываться сразу же, когда будет имитирован сигнал. Но когда Ваши объекты находятся в разных потоках, имитированные сигналы не будут вызывать слот сразу, они будут помещены в цикл событий потока, и будут исполнены, когда придёт их очередь, т.е. сигнал не сможет быть доставлен(слот не сможет быть вызван), пока не закончится выполнение той функции, в которой был имитирован сигнал. У Вас бесконечный цикл, поэтому и все Ваши сигналы на очереди исполнения. Остановите Вашу функции)) и удивитесь, сколько же раз будет вызван слот ;)

В Вашем случае, решение проблемы, это указать в connect пятым аргументом DirectConnection. Но это не рекомендуется делать по документации qt, потому что это не безопасно, если объекты находятся в разных потоках.
Всё, что я сказал, есть в док.

Comment: Хотя нет, func находится в основном потоке, события сигнала достаются туда, там нет бесконечного цикла, должно работать и так.

Comment: Всё, понял. всё нормально) просто функция sleep имеет такой прототип: QThread::sleep(unsigned long secs); задаётся в секундах, а у Вас 1000 стоит ;).
Проверил, всё работает)

Comment: Да, все понятно, большое спасибо!